# How can my application assign a keyboard shortcut in the system from Flatpak?

Tags: gnome, vala, flatpak

I am the developer of [Planner](https://github.com/alainm23/planner) and I am having a problem assigning a [keyboard shortcut](https://github.com/alainm23/planner/issues/246) to the current system.

Planner is a task manager and has a built-in application called Quick Add that through a keyboard shortcut that can be run regardless of whether Planner is running.

[image]

To install this keyboard shortcut I use the following [service](https://github.com/alainm23/planner/blob/master/src/Services/CustomShortcutSettings.vala).

This works perfectly if I build Planner from the repository. However, I have an error if I execute the same function if I build Planner from Flatpak

```
** (com.github.alainm23.planner:2): WARNING **: 15:54:36.510: CustomShortcutSettings.vala:28: Schema "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys" is not installed on your system.
```

I know that I can't access the scheme of `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-key` And I need a hole to edit the dfcon configuration of the system.

The question is how can I do that. If anyone could help me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Flatpak by default [doesn't allow editing GSettings in a way that affects the rest of the desktop](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2019/07/12/settings-in-a-sandbox-world/), since rouge applications could use that ability to do things with security and privacy implications, like set or unset proxy servers.

So it would be best to look into alternative ways to make this possible - perhaps provide people with instructions to set it up manually, or [request and/or contribute](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/issues) proper portal support for setting global keyboard shortcuts.

If you still really want to implement this, check the link above for the details on the sandbox hole you need to open to make it work.